# Catia enumeration values when using Python (Original title:accessing CATIA object in python)

Tags: python, catia

I'm trying to do some design automation in CATIA. I'm using python, I then record macros in CATIA and translates the code there to python code. Now I have stumbled upon a problem.

Below is the Macro from CATIA that i want to translate into pyhton code.

```
Language="VBSCRIPT"

Sub CATMain()

Set productDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

Set product1 = productDocument1.Product

Set product1 = product1.ReferenceProduct

Set constraints1 = product1.Connections("CATIAConstraints")

Set reference1 = product1.CreateReferenceFromName("ContainerSchiff/Container1/!yz plane")

Set reference2 = product1.CreateReferenceFromName("ContainerSchiff/Container0/!Geometrical Set.1/Point.2")

----Here is the problem ----   Set constraint1 = constraints1.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeDistance, reference1, reference2)

Set length1 = constraint1.Dimension

length1.Value = 300.000000

product1.Update 

End Sub
```

When translating this i have no idea what to do with `catCstTypeDistance`

If I leave it as is, then python will obviously complain about the name not being defined. If I pass it as a string complains as well. Below is the part of the python

```py
else:
    add_container_skeleton(product1,i)
    product1.ReferenceProduct
    constraints1=product1.Connections("CATIAConstraints")
    Name1="ContainerSchiff/Container" + str(i-1) + "/!Container1/yz plane" 
    Name2="ContainerSchiff/Container" + str(i) + "/!Geometrical Set.1/Point.2"

    reference1= product1.CreateReferenceFromName(Name1)
    reference2 = product1.CreateReferenceFromName(Name2)

    constraint1 = constraints1.AddBiEltCst('catCstTypeDistance', reference1, reference2)

    length1 = constraint1.Dimension
    length1.Value = 300.000000
```

and the two different error messages that I get.

```
File "C:\Users\Mange\Documents\LIU\Catia part 2\first_draft.py", line 179, in place_containers
    constraint1 = constraints1.AddBiEltCst('catCstTypeDistance', reference1, reference2)
  File "<COMObject Connections>", line 3, in AddBiEltCst
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'catCstTypeDistance'
```

```
File "C:\Users\Mange\Documents\LIU\Catia part 2\first_draft.py", line 179, in place_containers
    constraint1 = constraints1.AddBiEltCst(catCstTypeDistance(), reference1, reference2)
NameError: name 'catCstTypeDistance' is not defined
```

How can I "access" this thing/object(?) from python?

Comment: This is a good question to have here. The title could be better targeted for searching, as "assessing the CATIA object" has a specific meaning in CATIA automation  - it refers to getting the CATIA application object. A better title might be "Creating annotations in CATIA using Python" or "Catia enumeration values when using Python"

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

When not in CATIA itself `catCstTypeDistance` must be replaced with an integer corresponding to the constraint type. Which number corresponds to which constraint type can be found here http://catiadoc.free.fr/online/interfaces/enum_CatConstraintType.htm

Answer (score 0):

The best way IMO, and not to use integers (and spend time translating them) is to use **makepy** to early bind the COM object.
After that, you'll have constants listed in the relative .py files generated from the Type Libraries.
After that, by importing:

```
from win32com.client import constants as CATEnum
```

**and only after** having obtained the Application object:

```
CATIA = Dispatch('CATIA.Application')
```

you will be able to access them:

```
CATEnum.catCstTypeDistance
```